# Need Help to integrate Deep Link Routing to Content in Xcode Project Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, deep-linking, appdelegate

I have two issues when I try to add Branch's deep link routing to content in my project.

1. Need to find the itemid from array.
   Currently, I am showing a list of items from homePageArray, in my homepage.m, and when user click on the item display it will redirect them to ItemDetailPage based on the selected index.

   ```
   ItemDetailPage * itemDetailPageObj = [[ItemDetailPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"ItemDetailPage" bundle:nil];
   [itemDetailPageObj detailPageArray:homePageArray selectedIndex:tag];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:itemDetailPageObj animated:YES];
   [itemDetailPageObj release];
   ```

But since the param is itemid, from the deep link. I will need to find the index in homePageArray that has the itemid. But I am not sure how to find it. (In the homePageArray, each item has a name, id and content.)

2. I have problem adding deeplink launch sequence in AppDelegate.m. Below is the instruction from Branch's Deep Link

   ```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   // initialize the session, setup a deep link handler
    [[Branch getInstance] initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                     andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
   NSString *itemid = [params objectForKey:@"itemid"];
   int tag = "index of homePageArray based on the above itemid";
   if (itemid) {
      ItemDetailPage * itemDetailPageObj = [[ItemDetailPage alloc]initWithNibName:@"ItemDetailPage" bundle:nil];
      [itemDetailPageObj detailPageArray:homePageArray selectedIndex:tag];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:itemDetailPageObj animated:YES];
      [itemDetailPageObj release];
      }
   }
   ```

The problem is I cannot launch self.navigationController in AppDelegate.m, so I wonder what is the workaround to the above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you can use

```
NSUInteger i = [ homePageArray indexOfObject: itemid ];
```

to get the index of the item you are looking for.

To answer your second question of pushing the detail page onto the navigation view controller, you should not be calling `self` since it refers to the AppDelegate in this case. You should need to get a reference to the Homepage ViewController and call something like

```
[homepageVC.navigationController pushViewController:itemDetailPageObj animated:YES];
```

Sometimes performing UI changes in a different thread will cause funky behavior, so I recommend doing this in the main thread. Put this code withing your callback.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                 ^{ 
    // Push view controller here
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did it with your advice. Thank you so much again.